# how to send data from an activity to interface

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

i have an activity . which gets me a user id . and i want to get it into an interface,(seems like a stupid question to me too)

for eg. 
code snippet. (to show what i want to get done)

**ACTIVITY**

```
class MainActivity extends Activity{

         public static string user;
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
         {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                user="1";  //I WANT TO SEND THIS VALUE TO MY INTERFACE SHOWN BELOW
         }
}
```

**INTERFACE**

```
package random.test.done;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface RequestExample{

    @GET("claim.php?id=1" + MainActivity.user); /// how to get that user data here ? 
    Call<JSONResponseClaim> getJSONClaim();
}
```

@GET("claim.php?id=1" + MainActivity.user); // this line in the interface gives error when hover over MainActivity.user (Attribute value must be constant)

**questions are in the comments in the above code snippets**

Comment: Why this `public void main(String[] args)` ?

Comment: opps, sorry, being a java developer, did that by mistake (out of habbit), editted the post :) thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should fix your `RequestExample` method

```
@GET("/claim.php")
Call<JSONResponseClaim> getJSONClaim(
    @Query("id") Integer id,
    @Query("user") String user
);
```

Then use it on your activity like this

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://myendpoint.com")
    .build();

RequestExample service = retrofit.create(RequestExample.class);

Call<JSONResponseClaim> call = service.getJSONClaim(1, user);
```

Hope it helps.

Also if you want to check some samples:

> https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/samples/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit